# How can I mock a subroutine for Unit testing in Perl?

Tags: perl, unit-testing, cpan

Here I am giving the pseudocode for for the subroutine which need unit testing to be done.

```
sub get_detail_team(param1,param2){

   my $dbh   = connect to databasehandle
   my sql    = get_sql_details(param1,param2)
   my $sth   = $dbh->prepare($sql)
       $sth->execute()
   my $result = $sth->fetchall_arrayref();

return get_html_content($result,prama)
}
```

the get_sql_details() and get_html_content()  are also the sub routines which are in the same package.
How can we unit test the get_detail_team() function?

I have tried using this `Test::Mockmodule` but did not get the exact results.

Comment: Could you show your mock code that didn't work as expected?

Answer (score 5):

I don't think this is a good candidate for mocking.

First problem is `get_detail_team` does two things, it gets the data *and* it formats it.  Formatted data is harder to test than data structures.  Separating formatting from functionality makes things much easier to test and it makes it easier to add more formatters.  One Extract Method refactoring later...

```
sub get_detail_team_data($param1, $param2) {
   my $dbh   = connect_to_database;
   my $sql   = get_sql_details($param1, $param2);
   my $sth   = $dbh->prepare($sql)
   $sth->execute();
   return $sth->fetchall_arrayref();
}

sub get_detail_team($param1, $param2) {
    my $detail_team = get_detail_team_data($param1, $param2);
    return get_html_content($detail_team);
}
```

Now we can focus on testing just the data.  Looking at `get_detail_team_data` it's just a thin wrapper around `get_sql_details`.  To test `get_sql_details` you'd want to get the SQL and see if it fetches the data its supposed to which is what `get_detail_team_data` does.  You might as well focus testing on `get_detail_team_data` with only basic integration tests of `get_sql_details`.  That leaves the problem of the database connection.

I'm not a fan of so much mocking that all external services have been removed.  If you're going to be writing SQL, you need a SQL database to run it against, else you're not really testing the functionality.  I'm going to assume the existence of a test database with a schema which matches the production database.  Your tests can populate it with whatever data they like and rollback at the end of the script.

Simplest thing to do is to write `connect_to_database` so it honors a testing environment variable to connect to a test database.  Even better is to have an environment variable which controls where the whole system looks for its configuration information that the whole test suite can take advantage of.

`get_detail_team` is not worth much testing, it's just a thin wrapper.  Write basic integration tests for it and focus on testing `get_html_content` which you can just pass a data structure.

Comment: Dependency injection is a critical tool in unit-test, but I can understand the concern re sql-protocol interop is not a part of unit-test but is a part of feature-rest. Sending payload to a 'stub' server which allows a unit-test to assert on content presented would not be a validation of query composition. One should do feature-test against a bonifide sql-server, but query-composition needs unit-test.

Comment: @msudder In many causes it's so cheap to spin up a local SQL server with the production schema and load some test data in a transaction, it might as well be the "stub" server. Writing a fake SQL server and its fixtures seems to be unnecessary work, complexity, limitations; one more piece of code to maintain, and one more source of bugs. One, unfortunately very common, situation where mocking is necessary is when it isn't easy to spin up a SQL server, or it isn't easy to load test data (because it's too interconnected, or the tools aren't there) which IMO is a technical testing debt.

Comment: @msudder Look at it another way, what if we tried to pure unit test `get_sql_details($param1, $param2)`? What does it do? 1) It produces valid SQL and 2) said SQL returns the correct data. For 1) we could use a generic SQL validator, but SQL is varied; it won't tell us how it works for real, and its syntax might be more restrictive causing a false negative. For 2) we could do static analysis of the SQL to guess what it might do, but that won't really tell us if it will work, and might produce false negatives. Why bother? Just run it through the real database, it's the best validator.

Comment: good counter, I like your point on using sqlite as stub response!